# Reply-To Email header not working anymore

Tags: email, thunderbird

First of all: My reply-to header always worked for 2 years.. Thunderbird never had a problem with it and still doesn't have any problem on my Mac.

My shop contact form sends me the email from info@webshop.com and adds the reply-to header from the customer
The source of the email is:

```
Return-path: <sterntau@s207.rackspeed.de>
Envelope-to: info@sterntaufe-deutschland.de
Delivery-date: Mon, 04 Nov 2013 18:00:05 +0100
Received: from sterntau by s207.rackspeed.de with local (Exim 4.80.1)
(envelope-from <sterntau@s207.rackspeed.de>)
id 1VdNVV-001tmU-Gn
for info@sterntaufe-deutschland.de; Mon, 04 Nov 2013 18:00:05 +0100
To: =?utf-8?B?aW5mbw==?= <info@sterntaufe-deutschland.de>
Subject: =?utf-8?B?S29udGFrdGZvcm11bGFy?=
Reply-To: customer@gmail.com
From: Sterntaufe-Deutschland <info@sterntaufe-deutschland.de>
Date: Mon, 04 Nov 2013 17:00:05 +0000
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8
Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable
Content-Disposition: inline
MIME-Version: 1.0
Message-Id: <E1VdNVV-001tmU-Gn@s207.rackspeed.de>

=0A=0AName: Test=0AE-Mail: customer@gmail.com=0ATelefon: =0A=0AKommentar: Test
```

Normally it should reply to customer@gmail.com which always worked till yesterday.
From yesterday its not working anymore. On all emails! Even on those where it worked before.
But it works fine if I send a normal E-mail from my Gmail account to my info@webshop.com account.
Reply-To works like it should then. Just not for the contact form
Thunderbird recognizes the reply-to email as it shows "Reply to: customer@gmail.com" below the subject. But still uses my info@webshop.com when I click "reply"

I also tried to re-install thunderbird, install thunderbird on a clean VMware. Install Thunderbird on another laptop.. all the same.
But it still works with Microsoft outlook

Please help me

Comment: My Gmail Account on Thunderbird still uses the reply-to email too

Answer (score 1):

It is a BUG of Thunderbird 24.1.0 https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=933555